# How to handle multiple requests simultaneously in a windows service using multi-threading or any other mechanism in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, service

I have created a service as my code  below shows, which on start reads a config file and connects to an instance of a web application, and authenticates against that web application (credentials are read via the config file), and then doing few operations.

I want to extend my service to handle multiple web applications at the same time using threading. Any ideas how can I achieve this?

Each web application will have a separate config file, such that my service should read each config file and then spawn a new thread to handle the request.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {

        try
        {
            m_Thread = new Thread(StartService) {Name = "My service"};
            m_Thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //  throw ex;
            FailStart();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a service if you make few web service calls ? As for the communication with web service(s) consider using async/await instead of spawning the threads. In general you don't need any new thread at all to perform I/O operations.

Comment: I am not only making webservice call but also doing many other operations. And this is designed as service and now cant change it. Is it possible to spawn one thread for each application defined in config files so the request can be served parallel.

Comment: It's possible but not so efficient. Using asynchronous I/O for that would be a better practice.